GlassFish 4.1 CPU usage increase
Good morning, I would greatly appreciate your help as I am quite lost. For approximately 4 to 5 years, I have had an ERP software running on GlassFish on an AWS EC2 instance. A little over a month ago, it started failing, with one CPU core remaining at 100%. When performing a thread dump, I attach the log of what I find. Beyond the failure itself, why could this have occurred after 4 years without any updates or software changes?
     "Thread "http-listener-3-kernel(1) SelectorRunner" thread-id: 58 thread-state: RUNNABLE
 at: sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.epollWait(Native Method)
 at: sun.nio.ch.EPollArrayWrapper.poll(EPollArrayWrapper.java:269)
 at: sun.nio.ch.EPollSelectorImpl.doSelect(EPollSelectorImpl.java:93)
 at: sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.lockAndDoSelect(SelectorImpl.java:86)
 at: sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectNow(SelectorImpl.java:105)
 at: org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.select(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:114)
 at: org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:338)
 at: org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:278)
 at: org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
 at: org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
 at: java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"


This is a known issue in the Grizzly component of GlassFish, that happens due to a defect either in the operating system or older versions of Java.
GlassFish 4.1 contains a workaround, but it's applied only if you use Java 1.6 or lower. There's no way to force this workaround in other cases.
If you already use GlassFish 4.1 or you upgrade to it or a newer version then this workaround should be applied automatically if GlassFish runs on Linux. If it's not then you can force this workaround by setting the system property org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.force-selector-spin-detection to true.
More info about this in:

https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/grizzly/issues/1749
https://github.com/javaee/grizzly/issues/1801
https://github.com/javaee/grizzly/issues/1967


If you need help with GlassFish, my company OmniFish is ready to help you:
